# Why IWorkbenchPage page is null when I try to open an editor in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I found this example code:

```
File fileToOpen = new File("externalfile.xml");

if (fileToOpen.exists() && fileToOpen.isFile()) {
IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(fileToOpen.toURI());
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

try {
    IDE.openEditorOnFileStore( page, fileStore );
} catch ( PartInitException e ) {
    //Put your exception handler here if you wish to
}
} else {
//Do something if the file does not exist
}
```

When I run my plugin, eclipse report that IWorkbenchPage page is null.

I implement my code in this way:

```
public void openFile(Path filepath) throws Exception
{
    File fileToOpen = new File(filepath.toString());

    if (fileToOpen.exists() && fileToOpen.isFile()) {
        IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(fileToOpen.toURI());
        IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

        try {
            IDE.openEditorOnFileStore( page, fileStore );
        } catch ( PartInitException e ) {
            //Put your exception handler here if you wish to
        }
    } else {
        //Do something if the file does not exist
    }               
}
```

Method openFile is called from another method in the same class.

and this my SampleHandlers (that I don't write myself):

```
public class SampleHandler<IWorkspace> extends AbstractHandler {

public SampleHandler() {
}

public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException { 
    String pagetitle = "";
    String worspacelocation = "";

    try{
    //salvo in workspacelocation il path del workspace
    worspacelocation =ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Workspace Location Error");
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Impossibile determinare il workspace");     
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    try{
    IEditorPart editor = HandlerUtil.getActiveEditor(event);
    if (editor.getTitle() != null)
    {
        pagetitle = editor.getTitleToolTip();       
    }   
    else
    {
        pagetitle = null;
    }}
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print("errore:" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();}   
    NewFrame.main(null, pagetitle,worspacelocation);        
    return null;
}
```

Comment: When are you running this? There will only be an active page when Eclipse is fully up and running.

Comment: I running this when I run my plugin: run as->eclipse application.

Comment: You can't run just that. Is this a command handler? A menu item? Something in an activator? Show us some more complete code.

Comment: I edit my ask. Sorry but I add my project to plugin that I have not implemented

Comment: You appear to be trying to use Swing code here, you can't mix Swing with SWT code unless you use the `SWT_AWT` bridge code.

Comment: yes but that is for another part of project...I simply open a file with an editor into eclipse.

Comment: You still have not shown us where you call the openFile from. If you are doing this from Swing or anything other than the SWT UI thread you will likely get null. We need to see an [mcve] that we can test.

Comment: method OpenFile is callad from another class that do a file xml. I call method in this way: openFile(filecopy);